USB hub suddenly does not work as expected
I'm having an issue with my USB-C hub which suddenly cannot both charge my laptop and connect my screens.
I'm on an up-to-date version of Ubuntu (24.04.1), and I have a USB hub connected to two screens with an HDMI interface.
Until yesterday, I could have both charging and the screens displayed, but since yesterday, when I connect the USB-C plug into the laptop, I cannot have both. If the charging icon shows that the computer is charging, the displays are not recognized, and if I unplug and replug enough, sometimes the charging icon does not display but the screens are not recognized.
May an update be the reason it keeps failing? How can I correct this issue?

Apparently, the issue came from my last firmware update on my computer. I applied the latest patch and I can use both screens and charge at the same time.
